# Finding Text using regex in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I know finding text in ColdFusion is quite easy using `find` or `findNoCase`, but I have code where I need to make some regex search so I can use that portion of a `<div>` in code.

I have the following code in my text file:

```
<div class="portion1">
    data and html code inside 
<div>

<div class="portion2">
    <div>Participation</div>
<div>
```

I want to fetch everything between "portion1" and "portion2" with ColdFusion and use it in a variable. I know this is somewhat regex based, but do not know much ColdFusion and would appreciate some guidance.

Let me add what I have tried so far:

```
<cfset portion1 = REMatch('(?s)<div class="portion1">.*?</div>', kk)>
            #portion1#
```

Comment: As written, your question is likely to be [closed as off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow works differently than a forum. Questions are expected to demonstrate that you have made some effort to solve the problem and should include the code you have tried and a description of how the the results differ from what you expected (and any error messages).

Comment: "everything between portion1 and portion2" Is this what you want to fetch? ">
data and html code inside 
<div>

<div class="

Comment: yes, its rematch so i know it will return me results as an array

Comment: It's hard to understand what is that you want. Do you want to read a text file as input? Show some expected output.

Comment: @James Your html isn't correct, care to update? Also, add ur desired o/p.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend integrating & using jsoup. You can select any HTML elements (similar to jQuery) and process the results using ColdFusion.  I use it to remove ads from feeds and rewrite HTML when sending email to make it more compatible.

- [jSoup: Java HTML Parser](https://jsoup.org/) (Official Site)
- [jSoup adds jQuery-like parsing in Java](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/04/06/jsoup-adds-jQuerylike-parsing-in-Java/)
- [Parsing, Traversing, And Mutating HTML With ColdFusion And jSoup](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-parsing-traversing-and-mutating-html-with-coldfusion-and-jsoup.htm)
- [Scraps, scrapes and soup](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/scraps-scrapes-and-soup.html)